# System.Math un identified

Tags: c#, mathematical-optimization

```
using System;    
using System.Math;    
class test

  {    
    public static void Main()    
      {    
        Console.Write("Enter any  value: ");    
        string s=Console.ReadLine();    
        double n = double.Parse(s);    
        double r = Math.sqrt(n);    
        Console.WriteLine(r);    
        Console.ReadKey();    
      }    
  }
```

I feel that every thing is clear in this code, but this code is giving compile errors:
A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Math' is a type not a namespace

How to use math functions?
Where do we get a list of all math functions available in Math class?

Thank You.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Math is a static class, not a namespace.  It is located in the System namespace.
Therefore, you only have to include the System namespace.
Simply use Math.Sqrt and drop the "using System.Math;"  Note that it is Math.Sqrt and not Math.sqrt

Hope that helps ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Starting with C# 6.0, you can use

```
using static System.Math;
```

if you don't want to write `Math.` all the time.

Comment: @Gokul any chance to change this as the accepted answer?

Comment: @RRUZ any chance to change this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5):

You've got a case sensitivity problem

```
double r = Math.Sqrt(n);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math_members(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

remove `using System.Math;`

You do need to reference `Math` class like above. `using System;` is enough

For reference and sample use, see [**Math Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx)